# issue with async function and reading line by line from a text file

Tags: javascript, node.js, asynchronous

I have the following code:

```
async function scrape_profile_list() {
    const rl = require('readline').createInterface({
        input: require('fs').createReadStream(__dirname + '/../resources/profiles.txt'),
        terminal: true
    });

    for await (const line of rl) {

        //throttle(function(){
            console.log('Scraping data for ' + line);
            var my_request = iterate_proxy();
            my_request.get({
                url: 'https://www.instagram.com/' + line + '/?__a=1',
                timeout: 5000,
                json: true,
                simple: true
            }).then((response) => {
                if (!response.graphql) {
                    console.log(line + ' needs verification');

                } else {
                    //Provided profile does not have enough posts. Bail out.
                    var username = response.graphql.user.username;

                    console.log(username + ' aman');


                }
            }).catch(function (err) {
                console.log(un);
                console.log(`${username} - HTTP Request error.`)
            });

        //});
    }

}
```

the particular issue is that in this line:

```
url: 'https://www.instagram.com/' + line + '/?__a=1',
```

i need the url to take the username from the line i am reading from file.. however when i do so only 1 request is made, but in the file i have 5 lines, so it should theoretically make 5 request

however when i hard code the

url to

```
url: 'https://www.instagram.com/nikitakusuma/?__a=1',
```

the request is made 5 times.. why is this ?? i am pulling my hair out

Answer (score 0):

why not using readFileSync ?

```
fs.readFileSync('/../resources/profiles.txt').toString()
  .split("\n");
```

getting your lines in an array then go and make a call foreach.